# How to access external css file linked to html which is used in tornado web server?

Tags: python, html, css, tornado

I am a newbie to tornado and I am working on a very basic tornado web deployment work.
I am trying to render a HTML file which is using an external css.
But I am unable to load the css. I am working on VScode and all the files are there in my explorer folder.
This is how I am trying to get access to html and css:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

class basicRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")

class staticRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("demo.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", basicRequestHandler),
        (r"/upload", staticRequestHandler)
    ])

    app.listen(8881)
    print("listening on port 8881")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

My demo.html file contains external css named design.css which I am trying to access like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css"> <!--here-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="drag-area">
            <img src="a.png" width="80px" height="100px" class="center">
                
            <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-size: xx-large;" class="default">Drag and drop files here</h4>

            <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-size: xx-large;">OR</h4>

            <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple class="button">

        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onClick="window.location.reload();">Refresh Page</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    
</body>
<button type="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</html>
```

All my files (design.css, demo.html etc) are in same folder which I imported in my vscode.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

welcome here. You would need a static file Handler as in here

```
import os

import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import threading, Queue

print('start Webserver')
SERVER_PORT = 9090

currenPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
resourcesPath = currenPath + '/ressources'

class IndexPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")

class webApplication(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r'/', IndexPageHandler),
            (r'/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': resourcesPath})
        ]

        settings = {
            'static_path': resourcesPath,
            'template_path': 'templates'
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ws_app = webApplication()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(ws_app)
    server.listen(SERVER_PORT);
    print('Listening on ',SERVER_PORT)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: sorry but can you please explain a little bit? I didn't get what is the use of template path. And also, should i make a new folder ressources inside my main folder  and put my css file there?

Comment: you wouldn't need it in that case but that is where you could leave html pages following the templates rules from tornado.. Which very probably is the next thing you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

If it is simple css, better to have in HTML. If it is like SPA, better have the minified file so that it avoid issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).